# How to close other shells except current?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, tty

I need a simple script to close other shells/sessions except the one I'm currently logged in. I'm stuck with this line:

```
ps -o pid,tty,comm | grep sh$
```

Which results in selecting the current shells.

For example:

```
 1346 136,0  sh
 1355 136,1  sh
```

I can use the `tty` command to know my current shell (pts). Then, I think I need a loop.

Comment: It is often a bad idea. You might use `pkill` on Linux.

Comment: Instead of "solved", you may want to mark as accepted one of the answers (the one that helped you the most).

Comment: None posted a simple-yet-complete solution. I thanked anubhava for his contribution. The funny thing is that a minute after asking, user vks posted a line that helped, but he deleted it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not as easy as it might seem at first. The main challenge is that the `ps` utility is rather incompatible between different platforms, which creates a very significant risk that assumptions you make about `ps` won't always be correct on systems where you might use the script. And since the task is a rather... *dangerous* one, you would want to be careful here. Just as an example, the `ps` on my current system (Cygwin) does not have a `-o` option, while yours appears to have one.

Anyway, here's my solution:

```
pidCol=$(ps| head -1| awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == "PID") { print(i); exit; }; };');
if [[ -n "$pidCol" ]]; then
    ps| tail -n+2| grep sh$| cut -c2-| awk "{ print(\$$pidCol); };"| grep -v "^$$\$"| xargs kill -9;
fi;
```

It first gets the column number in `ps`'s output that contains the PID of the process. I tried to make it as robust as possible by parsing the `ps` header line. So if the PID column position varies between systems, we should still get it correctly for the current system.

Then, I've applied a guard around the kill pipeline to ensure it only runs if we successfully got the `$pidCol` from the parse command.

Then, in the actual kill pipeline, I strip off the header, grep for all `sh` processes, cut off the first character (because `ps` on some systems prints a little character indicator at the beginning of *some* (but not all) lines that does not get a corresponding column name in the header line), and then use `awk` to just print the PID column value. Finally, I grep out the current process's PID and run the remaining PIDs through `xargs kill -9`.

Comment: I would format your code better! Your solution should work, at first glance!

Comment: You are using tail, grep, cut, awk and grep in the same line. I am sure this can be handled all together by awk.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `$$` here in this `ps` piped with `awk`:

```
ps -o pid,tty,comm | awk -v curr=$$ '$3 ~ /sh/ && $1 != curr'
```

The variable `$$` represents the PID of current shell.

Comment: Nice! I tried something similar, but yours is more direct. Note you may want to also say `NR>1` not to get the header.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, I think `/sh/` will also skip header line

Comment: Thank you for the $$ variable info.

Answer (score 1):

I use this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(tty | cut -d/ -f3-)
all=$(ps -A -o tty | grep pts/ | grep -v $current)
for i in $all ; do
    pkill -9 -t $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following to get the `PID` (Process ID) of running sessions:

`ps -ft`

Use those `PID`s to forcefully kill the process:

```
kill -TERM <PID1> <PID2> <PID3>
```

Use a loop in `BASH` to accomplish it for all, excluding the current session

Comment: Not `kill -9` (same as `kill -KILL`) but `kill -TERM`.

Comment: Doesn't `-9` means forcefully?

Comment: `-9` is generally `-KILL`, which is a *bad idea* to use at first: programs (including shell scripts, servers, etc...) may be prepared to handle the `SIGTERM` signal, but they cannot catch `SIGKILL`, which should be used as a last resort. Some programs (e.g. database servers, linkers, wordprocessors) may leave files on disk in an inconsistent state after a `SIGKILL`

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current shell with `tty` and "clean" it to get the data after the 2nd slash like this:

```
current=$(tty | cut -d/ -f3-)
```

Then, it is a matter of printing all the results in `ps -o pid,tty,comm` whose second column does not match your current one... and leaving the header out:

```
ps -o pid,tty,comm | awk -v current="$current" 'NR>1 && $2!=current {print $1}'
```

Then, you can loop through this result and `kill` the given PIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
pts=$( tty | sed 's/\/dev\(*\)/\1/' ) 
current=$( ps -C sh  | grep $pts | ps -o pid= | head -n 1 )
total=$(ps -C sh -o pid= )
for i in $total ; do                         
    if [[ $i -ne $current ]] ; then
            kill -9 $i
    fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pgrep -u $USER | grep -v "`pgrep -s 0`" | xargs kill
```

This grabs a list of all the PID's for the current user and removes the one for the current session. This is all then supplied via xargs to kill to terminate.